# Truncated file header while using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, multiprocessing, truncated

When I run the line:

```
def book_processing(pair, pool_length):
    p = Pool(len(pool_length)*3)
    temp_parameters = partial(book_call_mprocess, pair)
    p.map_async(temp_parameters, pool_length).get(999999)
    p.close()                                 
    p.join()
    return exchange_books
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_code.py", line 214, in <module>
    current_books = book_call.book_processing(cp, book_list)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/book_call.py", line 155, in book_processing
    p.map_async(temp_parameters, pool_length).get(999999)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
zipfile.BadZipfile: Truncated file header
```

I feel as though there is some resource that is being used that didn't close during the last loop, but I am not sure how to close it (still learning about multiprocessing library). This error only occurs when my code repeats this section relatively quickly (within the same minute). This does not happen often, but is clear when it does.

Edit (adding the book_call code):

```
def book_call_mprocess(currency_pair, ex_list):

    polo_error = 0
    live_error = 0
    kraken_error = 0
    gdax_error = 0

    ex_list = set([ex_list])

    ex_Polo = 'Polo'
    ex_Live = 'Live'
    ex_GDAX = 'GDAX'
    ex_Kraken = 'Kraken'

    cp_polo = 'BTC_ETH'
    cp_kraken = 'XETHXXBT'
    cp_live = 'ETH/BTC'
    cp_GDAX = 'ETH-BTC'

    # Instances
    polo_instance = poloapi.poloniex(polo_key, polo_secret)
    fookraken = krakenapi.API(kraken_key, kraken_secret)
    publicClient = GDAX.PublicClient()

    flag = False
    while not flag:
        flag = False
        err = False

        # Polo Book

        try:
            if ex_Polo in ex_list:
                polo_books = polo_instance.returnOrderBook(cp_polo)
                exchange_books['Polo'] = polo_books
        except:
            err = True
            polo_error = 1

        # Livecoin

        try:
            if ex_Live in ex_list:
                method = "/exchange/order_book"
                live_books = OrderedDict([('currencyPair', cp_live)])
                encoded_data = urllib.urlencode(live_books)
                sign = hmac.new(live_secret, msg=encoded_data, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper()
                headers = {"Api-key": live_key, "Sign": sign}
                conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(server)
                conn.request("GET", method + '?' + encoded_data, '', headers)
                response = conn.getresponse()
                live_books = json.load(response)
                conn.close()
                exchange_books['Live'] = live_books
        except:
            err = True
            live_error = 1

        # Kraken

        try:
            if ex_Kraken in ex_list:
                kraken_books = fookraken.query_public('Depth', {'pair': cp_kraken})
                exchange_books['Kraken'] = kraken_books
        except:
            err = True
            kraken_error = 1

        # GDAX books

        try:
            if ex_GDAX in ex_list:
                gdax_books = publicClient.getProductOrderBook(level=2, product=cp_GDAX)
                exchange_books['GDAX'] = gdax_books
        except:
            err = True
            gdax_error = 1

        flag = True
        if err:
            flag = False
            err = False
            error_list = ['Polo', polo_error, 'Live', live_error, 'Kraken', kraken_error, 'GDAX', gdax_error]
            print_to_excel('excel/error_handler.xlsx', 'Book Call Errors', error_list)
            print "Holding..."
            time.sleep(30)
        return exchange_books


def print_to_excel(workbook, worksheet, data_list):
    ts = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0]
    data_list = [ts] + data_list
    wb = load_workbook(workbook)
    if worksheet == 'active':
        ws = wb.active
    else:
        ws = wb[worksheet]
    ws.append(data_list)
    wb.save(workbook)
```

Comment: to me it sounds more like different processes share one file path (e.g. a zipfile in a temp directory) which one writes and the other reads at the same time while it is not fully written. Can you share the code which deals with the zipfile, in the function `book_processing`?

Comment: I am not sure where the zipfile comes into play. I write to an excel file, which may be it. I have added the code via edit. I have also added my print_to_excel function.

Comment: which one is `File "test_code.py", line 214, in <module>`? And: can you correct the indentation? (you best paste your original code, then select it and hit ctrl-k)

Comment: That line on test_code calls the book_processing function and passes in a string and a list. Correcting indentation now.

Comment: yes, it looks like the `print_to_excel('excel/error_handler.xlsx')` is the problem as it writes/reads the error file always at the same position. If two processes run this at the same time you run into the race condition that one reads the zip file while the other writes to it. Since xlsx is just a bunch of xml files in a zip container that's most probably where the error comes from

Comment: can you remove the line `print_to_excel` and see if the error goes away?

Comment: Very interesting - I did not know that xlsx is a bunch of xml files zipped together. I was confused about where the zip file was coming into play.

I moved the print_to_excel function to after certain processes close, and it seems to work well now. Thank you very much for the answer, and thank you for working through it with me. I learned a lot, and that is the important thing.

Comment: great that we found the root cause then. Moving the error handling to a place where fewer processes are open might just work for now, but the same bug might still hit you, just with a lower probability. I tried to summarize our findings into the answer below and also gave two solution which are guaranteed to not have this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the function `print_to_excel`

And more specifically in here:

```
wb = load_workbook(workbook)
```

If two processes are running this function at the same time, you'll run into the following race condition:

- Process 1 wants to open `error_handler.xlsx`, since it doesn't exist it creates an empty file
- Process 2 wants to open `error_handler.xlsx`, it *does* exist, so it tries to read it, but it is still empty. Since the `xlsx` format is just a zip file consisting of a bunch of XML files, the process expects a valid ZIP header which it doesn't find and it omits `zipfile.BadZipfile: Truncated file header`

What looks strange though is your error message as in the call stack I would have expected to see `print_to_excel` and `load_workbook`.

Anyway, Since you confirmed that the problem really is in the XLSX handling you can either

- generate a new filename via [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) for every process
- use [`locking`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes) to ensure that only one process runs `print_to_excel` at a time